# java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!

Tags: sql, hibernate, tomcat

Holas

Estoy trabajando con hibernate y tengo un problema con mi aplicación, no me conecta con la base de datos (sql).

Cuando miro el log del **tomcat** encuentro esto:

> (e-deas LTDA / CFC)[2018-04-27 10:05:40,830] | WARN | com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask | BasicResourcePool:1222 | com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@64dc420b -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30).
>       (e-deas LTDA / CFC)[2018-04-27 10:05:40,846] | WARN | org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory | SettingsFactory:103 | Could not obtain connection metadata
>       java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
>           at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:104)
>           at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:236)
>           at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(PoolBackedDataSource.java:94)
>           at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:35)
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:72)
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:1881)
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1174)
>           at com.edeas.hibernate.HibernateSessionFactory.(HibernateSessionFactory.java:31)
>           at com.edeas.hibernate.BaseHibernateDAO.getSession(BaseHibernateDAO.java:12)
>           at com.edeas.eParametrizacion.modelo.dao.CompaniaDAO.(CompaniaDAO.java:49)
>           at com.edeas.eParametrizacion.logica.CompaniaAction.findbyPrefijo(CompaniaAction.java:233)
>           at com.edeas.eSolicyTransp.logica.FileUploadAction.processFile(FileUploadAction.java:312)
>           at com.edeas.eSolicyTransp.logica.CargaAutomaticaFacturaAction.execute(CargaAutomaticaFacturaAction.java:122)
>           at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
>           at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
>       Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
>           at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:970)
>           at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:208)
>           at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:232)
>           ... 13 more

Mis propiedades para el archivo `hibernate.cfg.xml` son estas:

```
<property name="connection.username">xxx</property>
        <property name="connection.password">xxx</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">
            jdbc:sqlserver://10.60.1.132\xxxx;databaseName=db_CtrlFletes_dev
        </property> 


<property name="myeclipse.connection.profile">
            SQLServer (BD_CtrlFletes)
        </property>
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">
            org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
        </property>



<property name="connection.pool_size">20</property>
        <property name="connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
        <property name="connection.autoReconnectForPool">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">0</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">250</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">60</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">30</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">5</property>

        <property name="c3p0.autoCommitOnClose">false</property>
        <property name="c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin">false</property>
        <property name="default_batch_fetch_size">20</property>

        <property name="c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
        <property name="c3p0.acquireRetryDelay">1000</property>
        <property name="c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts">1</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements_per_connection">100</property>
```

Si alguien me pudiese ayudar se lo agradecería mucho.

Gracias

Comment: `<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements_per_connection">100</property>`porque lo tienes a 100??

Comment: ¿Cuánto es lo recomendado? Este es un desarrollo viejo y me lo pasaron, entonces no sabría decirte bien el por qué de las cosas

Comment: Si por lo general es 1

Comment: ¿Y crees que con eso quedaría el error solucionado? Porque lo intenté y sigo teniendo el mismo problema

Comment: Si no eso revisa que esten las librerias `webapp/web-inf/libs`

Comment: Ya revisé y allí están. Lo raro es que pruebo en mi máquina local y me funciona con la misma conexión, pero cuando la monto en el servidor sale ese error

Comment: Y el servidor si tendra acceso a la base de datos

Comment: es posible que al realizar operaciones dejes sesiones abiertas y el pool llega a su limite por defecto. Revisa tu codigo y cierra las conexiones em.close(); Saludos!